# I need to replicate some columns and add a rnorm in anotherone in an efficient way

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-science

I have a data.frame called datos with columns

```r
names <- c("TIPO","CODIGO","CANTIDAD","AVG_INGRESO_TOTAL","STDEV_INGRESO_TOTAL")
```

Where Tipo AND Codigo together are primary key.

Then "Cantidad" is the number of samples I need for that PK with AVG_INGRESO_TOTAL as the mean AND STDEV_INGRESO_TOTAL as deviation.

I need as a result a data.frame with columns

```r
c("TIPO","CODIGO","INGRESO")
```

where INGRESOS is the value of the samples repeted "CANTIDAD" times for each "TIPO","CODIGO".

I have already solved the problem in this way:

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(datos)) {
  d<-rnorm(datos$CANTIDAD[i],datos$AVG_INGRESO_TOTAL[i],datos$STDEV_INGRESO_TOTAL[i])

  for (h in 1:datos$CANTIDAD[i]) {
   vec <-data.frame(datos$TIPO[i],datos$CODIGO[i],d[h])
   names(vec)<-c("TIPO","CODIGO","INGRESO")
   distribucion <- rbind(distribucion,vec)
  }
}
```

But the result is an inefficient script that takes more than one hour to run for sum("CANTIDAD")=1.000.0000.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like for each `TIPO` and `CODIGO` pair you want a randomly generated number created by `CANTIDAD` draws of a normal random variable with mean `AVG_INGRESO_TOTAL` and standard deviation `STDEV_INGRESO_TOTAL`.

If so, the first thing to realize is you do not need to simulate `CANTIDAD` draws:

- If X_1, X_2, ..., X_n are all normal random variables with mean `M` and standard deviation `S`
- Then sum(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) is normal with mean `n*M` and standard deviation `sqrt(n)*S`

Hence your query can be reduced to:

```
answer <- datos %>%
    mutate(INGRESO = rnorm(1, CANTIDAD*AVG_INGRESO_TOTAL, sqrt(CANTIDAD)*STDEV_INGRESO_TOTAL) %>%
    select(TIPO, CODIGO, INGRESO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by` to subset by your primary keys and build data frames with each subset iteration. Below builds list of data frames to `rbind` **once** outside of looping.

```
df_list <- by(datos, datos[c("TIPO", "CODIGO")], function(sub) {
   d <- rnorm(sub$CANTIDAD, sub$AVG_INGRESO_TOTAL[1], sub$STDEV_INGRESO_TOTAL[1])

   data.frame(TIPO=sub$TIPO[1], CODIGO=sub$CODIGO[1], INGRESO=d)
})

distribucion <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```